# Regexp help: how can I detect if a string looks like "say [any number] [anything]"

Tags: regex, string

Without the []'s. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integers:

```
/^say \d+.*$/
```

But you might also want floating point:

```
/^say (\d+\.)?\d+.*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information presented a Perl Regular expression will look like `/^say \d.*$/` where `\d` matches the "number" and `.*` matches "anything".

Answer (score 0):

POSIX regex:

say [[:digit:]]+.*

Perl regex:

/say \d+.*/

Answer (score 0):

Regexes like those are fun. If your 'any number' is guaranteed to be an integer, you could do this:

```
/say \d+/
```

If you wanted to capture the number and the anything, you could do this:

```
/say (\d+) (.*)/
```

..which saves them using "groups".